# Problems with integration tests using Appium or Detox

Tags: react-native, appium, expo, detox

I have an app that I develop using the Expo and I'm trying to create integration tests.

But using Expo and integrating with Appium, it can not sync the servers (at least it seems):

- Run Appium server;
- Run Expo server;
- Run tests.

There are moments that work and others that do not.

With Detox is perfect, it works great for IOS but it still does not work for Android, it would have to export the project to react-native and make various settings and would not like to do that.

Could anyone give me a hint of other tools or how they currently do?

Comment: Do you have a repository anywhere with your successful Appium / Expo server running?